# java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

I can't figure out the reason for the above exception. I get this for every repository due to which I can't install new plugins to my eclipse download. I've seen many posts trying to resolve the problem but have had no luck with those solutions. My internal browser works properly and I've also disabled my anti-virus. I have tried

1. Using all methods in Network Connections(Native Manual Direct)
2. I've added and deleted the repositories
3. I've added / at the end of the URL and also tried using HTTPS.
4. I've checked and unchecked check-boxes available at in install new software

Still no luck. I've installed a few plugins before. The exact error is given below. (I'm using google DNS if that helps)

> java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:259)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
>       at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of your jdk and eclipse ?

Comment: Can you ping "download.eclipse.org" ?

Comment: I am using mars and jdk 1.8.0_45 and I can ping download.eclipse.org

Comment: @ada2161 : I am also facing the issue during maven build. Are you able to find a solution for this problem